# Send multiple dynamic metrics to Ganglia in logstash

Tags: ruby, logstash, ganglia

I want to cound the number of messages sent from different instances of program (nodes).
These nodes appear dynamically. The messages format will be like:

```
node01 - I feel like I'm loosing the grip.
node02 - I'm sad.
node02 - I'm loosing the reason to live.
```

I indend to parse logs and count statistics in Logstash (with `metrics` filter)
and then send them to Ganglia for display.
However, each call to `ganglia` output in Logstash only allows to send one statistic
(not an array like in Graphite output).
I only know how to achieve my Logstash configuration
with hardcoding of node names:

```
input { stdin { } }

filter
{
    grok { match => [ "message", "%{WORD:instance} - %{GREEDYDATA:data}" ] } 

    metrics
    { 
        meter => "events.%{instance}"
        add_tag => "metric"
        flush_interval => 1
    }
}

output 
{

    if "metric" in [tags]
    {
        ganglia
        {
            group => "node01"
            host => "239.2.11.71"
            metric => "events"
            metric_type => "uint32"
            value => "%{events.node01.rate_1m}"
        }

        ganglia
        {
            group => "node02"
            host => "239.2.11.71"
            metric => "events"
            metric_type => "uint32"
            value => "%{events.node02.rate_1m}"
        }

        stdout { codec => rubydebug { } }
    }
}
```

Maybe you could advise me how to create a configuration that is agnostic of node names?
I thought of looping through `events` array in `ruby` filter 
(which allows you to write arbitrary code), 
and creating new events, but I don't know how to create new event from code.

I also thought of splitting events using `multiline`, but I don't know how to translate
the `events` array to something splittable. I think I could use `gsub` in `mutate` filter, but
I'm not sure how to use it on array and how to obtain node names from it.

**Update**

I checked the included solution and it does not work either, I think Logstash only uses one output of one type. I would have to clone my outputs and tag them separately to make it work (not sure if this is possible). Anyway, it's not the desired solution, I only wanted to present better what I'm trying to achieve.